# Call enter key function after focus event query

Tags: jquery

I have a small project to do related to focus and enter key functions in query.

First, i would like to set focus on textarea, after that it will automatically call entry key to do something.

```
$('#textarea').focus(function(){
        var e= window.event;
        e.keyCode=13;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#textarea').focus(function(){
    var press = jQuery.Event("keypress"); //or keydown, keyup
    press.which = 13;.
    $(this).trigger(press);
});
```

see how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBFFH/1/